# How can I check data in half-hour intervals using query statements in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to check the data in half-hour intervals in Apache IoTDB?

I want to ask if I want to check the data at half-hour time intervals in Apache IoTDB, such as I need to check data at 9am, 9:30am, 10:00am, 10:30am and so on, how should I write the query statement in IoTDB to do that?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.